# Migrating from exported Hyper-V VM to ESXi

Tags: vmware-esxi, hyper-v, migration

Is is possible to directly migrate an exported Hyper-V virtual machine to ESXi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, download [VMware Converter](http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/); it can import a number of different formats, including Hyper-V, directly to an ESXi host.

Comment: It does, but only on a running Hyper-V VM or it's files, but not the exported Hyper-V machine. I want to get this conversion thing without deploying Hyper-V itself.

Comment: Marked as the correct answer. It seems there is no solution without having an running Hyper-V host.